# Wifi problems with Compaq CQ60-419wm running Athelos ar5009

Tags: wireless

I've tried almost everything i can find including Full Re-install of Kubuntu, And standard Ubuntu. A lot of people say its the drivers which are ATH5K driver which i have tried to run a new install of the driver, tried to run ndiswrapper(which removed my wireless completely) tried the madbull drivers, and tried a backporting the driver. none have worked. i added the computer type and wifi card type in the title just in case its one of those doing it instead.

this is a log of all of the wireless status.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7642556/

Comment: Please run the script is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: i posted my results just now so anybody can help along with some recently developed things i have seen like the light flickering and the wifi switch locking the wifi permanantly

Comment: I do not see the results of the script? did you paste them to pastebin like the directions said? if so we need the link.

Comment: Look at my first comment, read the directions then click on the link and follow the directions there.

Comment: I will be home soon and I will post.

Comment: I posted the answer that should fix your issue, you may have to reboot your computer and router.

Comment: Only one issue per question is allowed so it does not create confusion.

Comment: Understandable and i will open a new thread for that.

Comment: If it does not connect after you install the new driver run the script again and post a new wireless file so we can see the changes, but I believe it will.

Comment: Added more code to the beginning of the answer to include code to install dependencies.

Comment: should i do the make oldconfig command?

Comment: Start with this one `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms` and do all the commands again.

Comment: added a new pastebin changelist log. didnt work

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: United States why? I feel like removing window completely was a bad idea.

Comment: i added a little more detail about my computer to see if it is something with the computer+ubuntu combo and the things I've tried so there is less confusion.

Comment: UPDATE: i set up ubuntu standard and did all updates, i ran all the code lines posted and it went through. my network manager is working but it is still saying that the wlan0 status is disconnected. i will post an updated changelog for you to view now that i have updated.

Comment: I'M out of town until late tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Install dependencies required to compile the driver:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms
```

Go [here](http://drvbp1.linux-foundation.org/~mcgrof/rel-html/backports/) and download the newest driver to your computer then place the file on your desktop and right click and extract here.

Then compile the driver using the directions below.

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.15-rc1-1
make defconfig-ath5k
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -rv ath5k 
sudo modprobe -v ath5k
```

When you have an upgrade to the kernel you will need to do:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.15-rc1-1
make clean
make defconfig-ath5k
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -rv ath5k 
sudo modprobe -v ath5k
```